# Switching tabs moving up and down and side to side Out of Memory Error for one image

Tags: android

I have a CustomListAdapter that takes in mp3 and images in an array from 3 seperate tabs. When scrolling up and down and moving left to right I on occasion get this error and the app shuts down:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20813772 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 10MB until OOM
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:478)
                                                                                   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:508)
```

It happens when I add this one particular image.

Comment: Unless that bitmap is just huge, the image isn't your problem. Its everything in your app combined.  Take some heap dumps, and look for where your memory is being used with an emphasis for leaks.

Comment: How big is the image actually? You could try resizing it before displaying it in case it's much larger than the image view.

Comment: But when i remove the image.setresource the problem doesn't happen. Its an image selector with two images both are around 250kb

Comment: image size is 803x720 but displayed as 55x49 in the imageview

Comment: Yeah, your problem is everything else in your app

Comment: what do you mean  everything else in the app?

Comment: anyway I compressed files online and also made the images the same size as the image view seems to have done the job